# Tweepy: Search in stream api

Tags: twitter, tweepy

In Tweepy api for twitter I know we can search tweets by -

```
api.search(q="a and b")
```

Here it will search for both a and b appearing anywhere in the status in any order. However I need to do same for the Tweepy stream api, Is there any way to do that?

I know there is track field -

```
stream.filter(track=['a','b'])
```

But this would return status containing either of **a or b**, I need  both of the keywords in any order.

We could also do like, search for only **a** then manually filtering out status which contain **b**, but then we  would be discarding huge no. of tweets as stream api gives only 1% of the tweets

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done easily. Looking at the docs for the [Twitter API `track` paramenter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track):

> A comma-separated list of phrases which will be used to determine what Tweets will be delivered on the stream. A phrase may be one or more terms separated by spaces, and a phrase will match if all of the terms in the phrase are present in the Tweet, regardless of order and ignoring case. By this model, you can think of commas as logical ORs, while spaces are equivalent to logical ANDs. For example, `‘the twitter’` is `(the AND twitter)`, and `‘the,twitter’` is `(the OR twitter)`.

By this logic, to filter by `a` and `b`:

```
 stream.filter(track=['a b'])
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried it previosuly, but returned the results a and b coming together, like it searched for "a b".

I guess either the issue is with using track function of tweepy? Because I am using tweepy not twitter to stream tweets. I late found on a blog that there is no way to to do this in api of tweepy, just filter from A, get all the tweets then filter on B